# Laravel delete by BelongsToMany relationship

Tags: php, laravel

I have a `Task` class. And each record of this table can have one or many childs and can be one or many parents of another task.

Table **tasks**

```
id | name
```

Table **tasks_links**

```
parent_id | child_id
```

Task model

```
<?php

namespace App;

class Task extends Model
{    
    public function childs()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'tasks_links',  'parent_id','child_id');
    }

    public function parents()
    {
        return $this->belongsToMany(Task::class, 'tasks_links' , 'child_id' , 'parent_id');
    }
}
```

And in my controller and views
I can use the relationship like

```
Task::find($id)->parents(); //Return an array
```

When I delete a task, I would also to delete the links with other related tasks

So the following is working :

```
\DB::table('tasks_links')->where('parent_id' , $task->id)->delete();
\DB::table('tasks_links')->where('child_id' , $task->id)->delete();
```

But I the following is not working

```
foreach ($task->parents() as $parent) {
        $parent->delete();
    }
```

Is there any way to delete the `links` by using the `parents` and `childs` functions instead of searching directly in the database ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
$task =Task::find($id); 
$task->childs()->detach();
$task->parents()->detach();    
$task->delete();
```

Comment: $task->childs()->detach()

Answer (score 2):

The fastest way of doing this.. if every time you delete a task you will want to delete all relations you should just include this in your task migrations

`$table->foreign('the_foreign_key')->references('related_table_primary_key')->on('table_name_related')->onDelete('cascade');`

Every time you delete a task on relationships will  be deleted.

Answer (score 0):

What I usually do on these situations is, when designing the database, I write a migration and set what columns I want to be affected by cascade.

Example

```
php artisan make:migration cascade_implementation
```

and on the Up() I set whatever I wish to be affected, on Down() I set the inverse, in case of a rollback needed. In your case, something like (or the other way around, depending on your needs):

```
public function up()
{ 
Schema::table('tasks', function (Blueprint $table) {
  $table->foreign('parent_id')
        ->references('id')->on('tasks_links')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
  $table->foreign('child_id')
        ->references('id')->on('tasks_links')
        ->onDelete('cascade');
});
}
```

Read more at https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/migrations